# MySQL Cardinality Violation Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create an SQL Query where the User table is joined with Athlete table. In addition to this, I also want to count total entries in the Athlete_Event_Run table and Athlete_Personal_Run table. When I run this sql query on PHP, I get the SQLSTATE[21000] error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)' in /var/www/html/ibaleka/get_athlete_profile_extended.php:14
```

I have placed the SQL code in a stored procedure, this is what I thought it would be like:

```
  SELECT * FROM `User` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Athlete ON Athlete.UserID = `User`.UserID
  WHERE `User`.EmailAddress = emailAddress
  AND (SELECT Athlete_Event_Run.AthleteID, COUNT(*) AS TotalEventRun FROM Athlete_Event_Run WHERE Athlete_Event_Run.AthleteID = `User`.UserID GROUP BY Athlete_Event_Run.AthleteID)
  AND (SELECT Athlete_Personal_Run.AthleteID, COUNT(*) AS TotalPersonalRun FROM Athlete_Personal_Run WHERE Athlete_Personal_Run.AthleteID = `User`.UserID GROUP BY Athlete_Personal_Run.AthleteID);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your inner queries at the bottom don't make any sense. You are returning too many columns, 2 not 1. It is trying to do a conversion to a logical boolean for you, and you completely confused it.

were it to resolve to

```
and (1)
and (false)
```

it would have a chance. But you are not, as you have a column plus an aggregate (times 2 subqueries). Even 1 of them would have made it choke. You had two.

From the manual page [Subquery Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-errors.html)
Error 1241:

> You may use a subquery that returns multiple columns, if the purpose
>   is row comparison. In other contexts, the subquery must be a scalar
>   operand.